# What does "K-On!" refer to in the series?

Tags: k-on

I have been watching the English dub of it on public TV and I haven't seen any mention of *K-On* in the series itself (with the exception of the OPs/EDs).

So I am wondering, what does K-On refer to in the series? If it refers to nothing, then is there a particular reason/meaning to the name K-On?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"K-On" is pronounced the same as the word 軽音 *keion*, which means "light music" (in the Japanese sense, not the classical sense). The main characters are, of course, part of the light music club, which is the 軽音部 *keion-bu*. The "K-On club", if you will.

If you had watched it with Japanese audio, you would have probably noticed the word sprinkled all over the place (since they talk about the club a lot, obviously). The [eyecatches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7r5wq2gDpEM) (I forget for which season) also have audio of Yui saying "K-On". I suppose they must have changed the eyecatches to something else for the English dub.

Comment: that eyecatch appears in both season with the english dub but i assumed Yui was just saying the series title like they do with the Eyecatches of Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood

Comment: Oh, okay. I just wanted to make a note of that since you said that you hadn't seen any mention of "K-On" besides in the OPs/EDs.

Comment: well to be honest i actually forgot about those until i saw the youtube video